# d3js tree Disable click on Child nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on d3js tree I need to disable click on child node But I am not sure how to do that Any Ideas would be helpful

Example:
[D3JS Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrhm4.png)

In the above image If I click on node "20" It should not close the node "21" 
The click should be disabled on these child nodes(4,5,6,19,20,21)

here is my try:

```
  function click(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                    d.children.forEach(expand); 
                } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                clearAll(root);
                update(d);
            }
```

I am trying to expand when some click on the child nodes

Any Help would be appreciated Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: "d.children.forEach" will throw an error....

Comment: function click(d){

    if(d._children)
    {
  d.children = d._children;
  d.children.forEach(expand);
  d._children = null;
    } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
}    If i use the above function  I was able to expand all the nodes here i am trying to not close when we click on child nodes on node20. I tried with collapse as well it is closing but unable to expand when i click So finally  What I want is If click on child node nothing should work(Clicks),

Comment: It worked for me finally by using this function      function(d._children){d.children = d._children;
                        d._children = null;  }